# Updating certain properties of entity using EF6 without loading entire entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

*(This question has been asked on SO and i have read most of the related posts and try to implement based on the suggestions but still not working)*

- I am using EF6 ( not EF Core)
- I am also using DB first approach. So we have `.edmx` file and C# entities are created by edmx template ( not sure if that matters here)

I want to update certain properties of an entity without loading the entire entity.

```
    private async Task Monitor()
    {
        var timeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-8);
        var documents = await _dbContext.Documents
                        .Where(x => x.DocumentCreatedDateTime < timeStamp)
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            x.DocumentID,
                            x.DocumentCreatedDateTime,
                            x.ProcessStatusID,
                            ProcessStatus = x.ProcessStatus.ProcessStatusName,
                            x.CurrentErrors,
                            x.ModifiedDateTime,
                            x.VersionStamp                                
                        })
                        .ToListAsync();

        if (documents.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var document in documents)
        {  
            var docEntity = new Document();

            docEntity.DocumentID = document.DocumentID;
            docEntity.CurrentErrors = "Document has error";
            docEntity.ProcessStatusID = (int)StatusEnum.Error;
            docEntity.ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            docEntity.VersionStamp = document.VersionStamp;

            _dbContext.Documents.Attach(docEntity);
            var entry = _dbContext.Entry(docEntity);
            entry.Property(p => p.CurrentErrors).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(p => p.ProcessStatusID).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(p => p.ModifiedDateTime).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(p => p.VersionStamp).IsModified = true;
        }           

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

**Issue**
The document entity has several other properties (columns) that are required in the database. But this particular process does not need to update those properties. When `SaveChanges()` get invoked i get `EntityValidationErrors` error

**Update 1**
I think i can do `db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false` but not sure is that is the correct approach

> The xxxxx field is required.

Comment: *This question has been asked on SO* - What does that mean? Are you repeating an existing question?

Comment: not same but similar kind of question

Comment: Well, if you can ensure that the updates are valid it's OK to disable validation for one specific `SaveChanges` call.

Comment: @LP13 Better is EF SqlCommand option.